# datatables pesquisa

Tags: jquery-datatables

boas precisava de uma ajuda..
estou a usar o datatables.

tenho um form de pesquisa que ao clicar vai buscar correr um ficheiro php , onde envio por parâmetros os dados de pesquisa , alguns campos podem ir em null.

o file do php que vai a base de dados tem a seguinte estrutura

pesquisa.php

```
class dados{ public function getinfo($query,$key,$processo,$sigla,$datainicio,$datafim,$op)
```

}}

tudo bem ate aqui porque estou a gerar um ficheiro json. que depois vou ler no datatables esse ficheiro, mas assim fica muito lento e limitado.

ja estou a gerar o json.
 estou a tentar a ceder ao file mas não me carrega o datatble do ficheiro.php proque será?

```
 $('#pesquisa').dataTable( {        
           "processing": true,
                       "ajax":{
            url :"../../temp/pesquisa.php", // json datasource
            type: "post",
```

Comment: Não seria type: "get"?

Comment: e posso ter a função na mesma? no index.php onde faço a pesquisa onde posso pesquisar apenas por um campo, ou intervalo de data, o if que tenho é algo como isto    if (($key != "") or ( $processo != "") or ( $sigla != "") or ($opcao!="")or ( ($datainicio != "")and ( $datafim != ""))) { depois tenho o datatables para preencher...que só preenche se o if acontecer apos fazer o sumbit.... ja tentei meter get mas nada